# Batch compress multiple folders into individual zip files

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, automator, archive

I have dozens of folders that I need to compress into individual zip files.

If I select all of these folders in the Finder and do "Compress [X] Items," I get one zip file containing *all* of the folders, whereas what I want is one zip file *per* folder.

I tried creating a workflow with Automator using the "Create Archive" action, but it behaves the same way: inputting multiple files/folders outputs a single zip file. There's no way to specify that the action run on each item individually.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to avoid having to tediously run "Compress" in the Finder on every single folder one at a time. Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: I updated my answer to improve the code used to increment the zip archive filename so it emulates how the Finder context-menu Compress [n] Items command increments a filename.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code once again to remove the unnecessary `popd` and corrected a fatal typo in `for i in $bn*.zip; do`, which should have been `for i in $bn *.zip; do`. Note the space between `$bn` and `*.zip`, it was missing and shouldn't have been.  So please update it in your implementation otherwise it steps on `File Name 2.zip` when the `basename` has a space in it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an **Automator Service**<sup>1</sup> that becomes available in **Finder** when **Folders** are selected and *emulates* the *context-menus* **Compress [n] Items** *command* **except** it creates an *individual zip archive file* for each selected **Folder** in the *name* of the selected **Folder**.  If the **Folder Name.zip** file already exists then a `" 2"` (*space* 2) is appended to the *filename*, e.g. **Folder Name 2.zip**. This ensures an existing *zip archive file* is not touched and the *zip archive filename* will be automatically incremented as necessary.

<sub><sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave**, and later, an **Automator** *Service* is called a *Quick Action*. There are also other minor nomenclature differences but they should be more obvious when comparing them to pre-macOS Mojave Automator workflows.</sub>

**To Create the Service:**<sup>1</sup>

1. Open **Automator** and select **Service**<sup>1</sup> or **File** > **New** > **Service** If **Automator** is already open.
2. Set **Service receives selected** to **folders** and **in** to **Finder**.
3. Add a **Run Shell Script** *Action*, setting **Shell:** to **/bin/bash** and **Pass input:** to **as arguments** and add the following *code*:

   ```
   for f in "$@"; do

       dn="$(dirname "$f")"
       bn="$(basename "$f")"

       cd "$dn" || exit

       if [[ ! -e "$bn.zip" ]]; then
           ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent "$f" "$bn.zip"
       else
           n=2
           for i in $bn *.zip; do
               if [[ "$bn $n.zip" == "$i" ]]; then
                   n="$(( n + 1 ))"
               fi
           done
           ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent "$f" "$bn $n.zip"
       fi

   done

   afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Purr.aiff
   ```
4. Save the **Service** as: **Compress Folders Separately**

**To Use the Service:**

In **Finder** or on the **Desktop** select multiple **Folders**, then **right-click** and select **Compress Folders Separately** from under **Services**.

Or after selecting the target **Folders**, you can also click **Finder** > **Services** > **Compress Folders Separately** from the **menu bar**.

There you have it, a way to compress multiple folder separately and simultaneously at one time in individual zip archives while emulating how Finder creates a zip archive file. Meaning the zip archive contains preserved resource forks and HFS meta-data in the subdirectory __MACOSX and embeds only the parent directory name *source* in *destination-archive*, not the fully qualified pathname as when using `zip` (without `-j`) to create the archive.

**Image of Compress Folders Separately**

[image: Compress Folders Separately - Automator Service]

Comment: I checked both your solution and @ababak's. They give exactly the same result and ababak's is far easier to implement. I up voted both anyway.

Answer (score 27):

There's an alternative solution that's built-in if you don't want to use Automator and are fine with changing Archive Utility's settings.

1. Open the Archive Utility.app located in /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/
2. Go to File > Preferences
3. Change the "Use Archive Format" preference to "Zip archive"
4. Drag and drop the folders into its icon in the dock.

Comment: the nice thing about this option is you can set the Archive Utility.app preferences to move the original to trash after it finishes, it's not limited to folders. Is there a way to set up an Automator service to open with Archive Utility.app as a service if you want right-click as an option? I ran into a limitation as Archive Utility.app can't be selected using the Launch Application action.

Comment: @thepen, of course you can select Archive Utility as the Launch Application Action. You just need to select "Other…" and navigate to its location which is `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/` (you can press Cmd-Shift-G when the file select dialog is open to paste this path for quick navigation)

Comment: what's the difference between 'archive format' and 'zip archive'?

Comment: This method is a much easier work flow. I tried the command: for item in *; do zip "${item}.zip" "${item}"; done in the terminal but it didn't work right. Unknown as to why but I didn't want to take the time to figure it out. This worked just fine.

Comment: I've used this successfully to zip up EPUB packages before putting them in a Calibre library. The automator method, while excellent, doesn't see them as folders, but still as packages.

Comment: Some details have changed with OS updates. As of Ventura (13.1): Step (2); Go to Archive Utility > Settings. Step (3): In the setting for "Use Archive Format" select "Zip Archive". Works as expected.