# Batch compress contents within a folder using Mac Automator

Tags: macos, automator, script, folders, compression

I've seen an automator service that can zip multiple folders into separate zip files: [Batch compress multiple folders into individual zip files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225241/batch-compress-multiple-folders-into-individual-zip-files)

Can this be modified to enter the folder, compress the files within it, not the folder itself and move on to the next?

E.g Enter folder > Compress X items > Exit folder (repeat for next folder)

It would be even better if it used the folder name for the zip file and moved it outside the folder.

Comment: I wrote the accepted answer in the linked question and any script can be modified to do something else or a new script can be written; however, it really isn't clear what you are asking. For example you ask "Can this be modified to enter the folder, compress the files within it, not the folder itself", it is not clear whether you want the files within the folder to each be individually zipped or all in one zip file but not include the folder itself within the zip file. If it's the later, just remove `--keepParent` from the script.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just tried this an it works, this is the answer!

Comment: BTW I just modified the code slightly and recommend you use the new code while removing `--keepParent` from the script.